# Can images and tables be always placed immediately after the paragraph they are first mentioned, even if white-space needed to move to another page?

Tags: tables, floats, blank-page

I would like to ensure that when I mention a table/figure in the text, the figure/table will appear after that paragraph ends. Even if this means leaving the rest of the page blank and putting the figure/table onto the next page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can achieve this goal by loading the `float` package and always using the `[H]` location specifier after `\begin{figure}` or `\begin{table}`. Note that the `H` specifier should not be combined with any other location specifiers. Thus, `[Hhtbp]` is *not* a legal location specifier.

Note also that I said that it's *possible* to achieve your goal; I didn't say it's *advisable* to pursue it.

Comment: This appears to put the figure within the section, but not necessarily in the proceeding paragraph?

Comment: @JimBo: You haven't provided any LaTeX code showing what you're actually doing; I'm therefore not sure I understand your question. I was assuming that you have placed constructs such as `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` *between* rather than *inside* paragraphs. If that's the case, the `[H]` specifier will force the float to be placed at that location on the page or (if there's not enough space left on that page) at the top of the following page. Either way, no new paragraph is allowed to start until the float is placed. Do you want to pursue a different approach?

Comment: In addition, in one case I refer to two figures in the same section (in different paragraphs), however it waits until the end of the section and then puts both of the figures next to each other, I would like the figures to appear immediately following the paragraph

Comment: @JimBo: Please augment/edit your question to explain in detail what you're trying to achieve. Without these further details, it's going to be nearly impossible to diagnose the situation, let alone provide an answer.

Comment: After your first explanation I got it, it is behaving exactly as you describe now, apologies, the problem I reported was due to something else.

Comment: @JimBo - Glad to read that things are working correctly.